# How to prioritize requests in angular $http service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm working on an application with a large amount of lazy data loading. I would like to prioritize http requests based on 'priority' param.

This is the concept of using it.

```
$http.get(url, {params: query, priority: 1})
```

I was thinking of using $http interceptors. Something like that:

```
 angular.module('myModule')
.factory('httpPriorityInterceptor', function ($interval, $q) {
    var requestStack = [];

    return {
        request: function (config) {

            config.priority = config.priority || 3;

            requestStack.push(config);
            requestStack.sort(sortByPriority);

            if (isFirstToGo(item)) return requestStack.pop();

            deferred = $q.defer();

            var intervalPromise = $interval(function(){

                if (isFirstToGo(item)) {
                    deferred.resolve(requestStack.pop());
                    $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
                };

            }, 100);

            return deferred.promise;

        }   
    };
});
```

But I can't return promise here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by making use of `$http`'s timeout property, and use both `request` and `responseError` callbacks to save and execute each `$http` requests respectively.

Steps:

1. Lazily inject the `$http` service within the `request` callback process, this will be the only way to get the `$http` service because injecting it in the factory's function causes circular dependency.
2. Determine if the configuration passed in the `request` callback has been processed. If it has not been processed then add the configuration in the request stack and sort it by priority. Add a resolved promise in the timeout property of the configuration object, to cancel the current `$http` request. Finally return the configuration object.
3. Once the `$http` request has been cancelled, catch it in the `responseError` callback. If there are items in the request stack, pop the first item(config) and invoke it using the lazy loaded `$http` service. Lastly return a rejected promise using the rejection parameter provided by the callback.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CeBfY2tbVikzm0QTJAfx?p=preview)

```
angular.module('demo', [])

  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpPriorityInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('httpPriorityInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {


    var requestStack = [], // request stack
        $http = null; // http service to be lazy loaded

    return {
      request: request, // request callback
      responseError: responseError // responseError callback
    };

    // comparison function to sort request stack priority
    function sort(config1, config2) {
      return config1.priority < config2.priority;
    }

    function request(config) {

      // Lazy load $http service
      if(!$http) {
        $http = $injector.get('$http');
      }

      // check if configuration has not been requested
      if(!config.hasBeenRequested) {

        // set indicator that configuration has been requested
        config.hasBeenRequested = true;

        // set default priority if not present
        config.priority = config.priority || 3;

        // add a copy of the configuration
        // to prevent it from copying the timeout property
        requestStack.push(angular.copy(config));

        // sort each configuration by priority
        requestStack = requestStack.sort(sort);

        // cancel request by adding a resolved promise
        config.timeout = $q.when();
      }

      // return config
      return config;
    }


    function responseError(rejection) {

      // check if there are requests to be processed
      if(requestStack.length > 0) {

        // pop the top most priority
        var config = requestStack.pop();
        console.log(config);

        // process the configuration
        $http(config);
      }

      // return rejected request
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

  })

  .run(function($http) {

    // create http request
    var createRequest = function(priority) {
      $http.get('/priority/' + priority, {priority: priority});
    };

    createRequest(3);
    createRequest(1);
    createRequest(4);
    createRequest(2);

  });
```

To make sure that each request has been invoked in the right order, you can check the logs in the console tab or the requests in the network tab.

**Update:**

If you want your requests invoked in order (when the first request must finish before the next request invokes) then you can tweak my solution in the `responseError` callback to something like this:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9jXfhqKDUt2UKmMNb1Lo?p=preview)**

```
function responseError(rejection) {

  // check if there are requests to be processed
  if(requestStack.length > 0) {

    requestStack.reduceRight(function(promise, config) {
      return promise.finally(function() {
        return $http(config);
      });
    }, $q.when());

    requestStack.length = 0;

  }

  // return rejected request
  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

**UPDATE 06/16/2019**

As mentioned in the comments, the promise returned by prioritized requests do not return the expected promise resolution or rejection. I have updated the interceptor to accommodate such scenario by:

1. Saving a deferred promise relative to each http config.
2. Return the deferred promise in the `responseError` interceptor for sake keeping the resolution or rejection of the request.
3. Finally use the deferred promise in the iteration of prioritized requests.

---

**[DEMO](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/9jXfhqKDUt2UKmMNb1Lo?preview)**

```
angular.module('demo', [])

  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpPriorityInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('httpPriorityInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {


    var requestStack = [], // request stack
        $http = null; // http service to be lazy loaded

    return {
      request: request, // request callback
      responseError: responseError // responseError callback
    };

    // comparison function to sort request stack priority
    function sort(config1, config2) {
      return config1.priority < config2.priority;
    }

    function request(config) {

      // Lazy load $http service
      if(!$http) {
        $http = $injector.get('$http');
      }

      // check if configuration has not been requested
      if(!config.hasBeenRequested) {

        // set indicator that configuration has been requested
        config.hasBeenRequested = true;

        // set default priority if not present
        config.priority = config.priority || 3;

        // add a defered promise relative to the config requested
        config.$$defer = $q.defer();

        // add a copy of the configuration
        // to prevent it from copying the timeout property
        requestStack.push(angular.copy(config));

        // sort each configuration by priority
        requestStack = requestStack.sort(sort);

        // cancel request by adding a resolved promise
        config.timeout = $q.when();
      }

      // return config
      return config;
    }


    function responseError(rejection) {

      // check if there are requests to be processed
      if(requestStack.length > 0) {

        requestStack.reduceRight(function(promise, config) {
          var defer = config.$$defer;
          delete config.$$defer;
          return promise.finally(function() {
            return $http(config)
              .then(function(response) {
                defer.resolve(response);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                defer.reject(error);
              });

          });
        }, $q.when());

        requestStack.length = 0;

      }

      return rejection.config.$$defer.promise;
    }

  })

  .run(function($http) {

    // create http request
    var createRequest = function(priority) {
      return $http.get(priority + '.json', {priority: priority});
    };

    createRequest(3);
    createRequest(1).then(function(data) { console.log(data); })
    createRequest(4);
    createRequest(2);

  });
```

Comment: That's type of solution I was looking for. I will try to implemented it. Thanks!

Comment: ryeballar I liked your answer but the promises that you place in the request stack once copied don't seem to execute the previously promised code. Really a more elegant solution would be to defer execution at the point you place your request on the stack but I cannot find a good way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide an equivalent plnkr or or jsfiddle for such a case?

Comment: I tried implementing this. But unfortunately, it's making two requests and one of them is cancelled. Is there any solution?? @ryeballar

Comment: Surely this doesn't work. If you cancel a request, then you can't interact with the promise properly. For example if you have `createRequest(1).then(() => { console.log(response); });` it will never be hit because the first request is cancelled and the second request you create in the responseError method isn't tied to the first request

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your timeout

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
       (function (_deferred){
        var intervalPromise = $interval(function(){

            if (isFirstToGo(item)) {
                _defferred.resolve(requestStack.pop());
                $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
            };

        }, 100);
        })(deferred);
return deferred.promise;
```

Seems like it's getting lost on $interval. aswell your deferred was instanced globaly set a `var` before.

Comment: Yes you are right. But as I mentioned the problem is I can't return promise here. It's only accept 'config' object.

Comment: Digged arround a little in the $http.get method, don't see an opportunity to set your priority in this. Maybe create an own service to handle this and priority before you call $http.get?

`service.httpGet(url,{priority:1});`?

Answer (score 0):

This was not the right solution. You can achieve this by writing your own service to prioritize your api calls queue before calling http get .

This will not work for the following use case 
[Angular Http Priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968892/angular-http-priority)