# Angular: using $httpProvider to prioritize requests based on param

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to create a queue of http requests and stack them in whatever order I want and execute those requests in that order.. My goal is to create lazy calls (these calls only affect blocks in my page, not the entire page) without blocking the page making sure that those http requests get run last... The reason why I need them to get run last is because I have another interceptor that shows a loader every time an http request gets made.
I found the following answer which is exactly what I need done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454410/6301843 by @ryeballar

But when I implemented this into my application it gave me the following error `[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:`

I'm using a Node reverse proxy to allow CORS so all my files are served using that server.. I'm not sure what is causing this or what work around I can do to achieve my original goal.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your `$http` request intercepter is blocking the `$http` requests done by the `$compile` service to load directive template URLs. Without seeing the code we really can't help you.

Comment: @georgeawg sorry about that... this is what the code looks like http://plnkr.co/edit/KwjuDfIQ6agqmClMUKew?p=preview

Comment: Both demos in the answer by @ryeballar don't work. They both cause load failures with directives that use `templateUrl`. In fact there is a comment that says the answer doesn't work.

Comment: I realized that is the issue, directives that use templateUrl cause the problem. I'm clueless at this point how to do this :(

Comment: I don't think that answer ever worked. I don't understand how it got accepted and 4 upvotes.

Comment: I don't think it was a bad answer but I don't think is complete. Clearly it breaks when requesting html files. It does creates the call stack but the problem is that order is not guarantee, so catching them in the responseError is the right way to go, but doing a $q.when() in the timeout causes the exception when it requests files. :/ really frustrating, this seems like a very useful tool to have.

Comment: Tell me more about your other interceptor that "shows a loader every request". I would rather figure out how to accomodate that intercepter.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for your response, however I came to the conclusion that this wasn't possible using the setup I have in my application. Requests happen 1 at a time and I don't have a main component that registers all requests that need to happen, so there is no way to know the number of requests that need to occur. What I ended up doing was that for the specific  request I passed in a lazy flag that I intercepted in my loader interceptor so I didn't show the loader for it.

Comment: Also I identified the last request that was running in the page and emitted an event when that was done to then fire up my lazy request. I know this is not a good solution nor is something that I feel happy with but that is what the current setup allowed me to do. Again thanks for your time :)