# Angular Http Priority

Tags: angularjs, http

I am making lots of API calls in my applications i.e say 50.

The total time for completing all the api calls will be around 1 minute. The priority for all the api calls will 2. I have enabled the angular cache.

So in meantime if the user of my applications just want to focus on the some of the api calls among the all i.e say just 6 api calls.

Then once again I will project that 6 api calls with priority 1 .

But still I dont get what I aimed ? i.e these 6 api calls need to receive the data asap.

Kindly refer the below example code .

On Initial load :

```
for(var i=1,priority=19;i<=19,priority>=1;i++,priority--)  
{
$http.get("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld"+i+"?test=hari",{priority:2})
.then(function(response) { });
}
}
```

On some event click :

```
$http.get("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld7?test=hari",{priority:1})
.then(function(response) { });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want send multiple http request one shot then use `$q.all`

Inside the loop push the http requests to an array and send that http array at once.

```
var httpArr = []

for (var i = 1, priority = 19; i <= 19, priority >= 1; i++, priority--) {
    httpArr.push($http.get("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld" + i + "?test=hari", {
        priority: 2
    }))
}
$q.all(httpArr).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response[0].data) //1st request response
    console.log(response[1].data) //2nd  request response
    console.log(response[2].data) //3rd request response
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question was different. I need to prioritize an running API call dynamically. So I am projecting an another same api call with priority 1 . But yet I can't able to get that response of that API call quickly . i.e It does not reacts for the priority 1

Comment: don't call the http req inside the loop. create a separate function and put the request inside that function and call the new function inside the for loop. pass the `i` as argument to the function

Comment: Will that respond for the priority I assigned. My question was different yar. It concerns on the Priority