# AngularJs http request priorities and http interceptors

Tags: angularjs, http

I have been looking at an application I made a while back and there is a particular page where the details are being loaded last. Because of this, it seems to be queuing the request (there are more than 6 others before it) and that is causing the page to be slow.

I figured I could find a solution to prioritize these requests and I found this:

[How to prioritize requests in angular $http service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450443/how-to-prioritize-requests-in-angular-http-service)

So I created my version of it and added it to my interceptors:

```
// Add our auth interceptor to handle authenticated requests
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpPriorityInterceptor');
```

The interceptor looks like this:

```
function factory($injector, $q) {
    var requestStack = [], // request stack
        $http = null; // http service to be lazy loaded

    return {
        request: request,
        responseError: responseError
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function request(config) {
        // Lazy load $http service
        if (!$http) {
            $http = $injector.get('$http');
        }

        if (!config.hasBeenRequested) {
            config.hasBeenRequested = true;
            config.priority = config.priority || 3;

            console.log(config);

            // add a copy of the configuration
            // to prevent it from copying the timeout property
            requestStack.push(angular.copy(config));

            // sort each configuration by priority
            requestStack = requestStack.sort(sort);

            // cancel request by adding a resolved promise
            config.timeout = $q.when();
        }

        // return config
        return config;
    }

    function responseError(rejection) {
        // check if there are requests to be processed
        if (requestStack.length > 0) {
            requestStack.reduceRight(function(promise, config) {
                return promise.finally(function() {
                    return $http(config);
                });
            }, $q.when());

            requestStack.length = 0;
        }

        // return rejected request
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function sort(config1, config2) {
        return config1.priority < config2.priority;
    }
}
```

The problem is, it seems to be intercepting template requests too. I have no issue with that, but they are not resolving. Instead I get a lot of errors:

> Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] Failed to load template: app/accounts/accounts.html (HTTP status: -1 )

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you should know that every request such as html files , css file and ... comes into interceptor.
in your case you dont need to prioritize this files. so you can filter your request like:

```
if (config.url.toString().toLowerCase().includes("api")) {
    //place your functionality
}
```